# How to merge cells table that have same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a table. I want to merge table cells if the value of a property of the cell is the same as another like "Available" or "Not". I can't think how to do this in jQuery, JavaScript, or any other language.

---

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NO </th>
                <th> name </th>
                <th> 2018-1-1 </th>
                <th> 2018-1-2 </th>
                <th> 2018-1-3 </th>
                <th> 2018-1-4 </th>
                <th> 2018-1-5 </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> 1 </td>
                <td> Mark Tony </td>
                <td>Available  </td>
                <td>Available  </td>
                <td>Available  </td>
                <td>Not  </td>
                <td>Not  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 2 </td>
                <td> Susan Tom </td>
                <td>Not  </td>
                <td>Available  </td>
                <td>Available  </td>
                <td>Not  </td>
                <td>Not  </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: just need to do this manually by checking table tags. if the value is the same with previous one and is in the same tr tag, then remove it

Comment: I need a script if I have big table..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to combine morethan 2 duplicate rows and sum the value in html table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008224/how-to-combine-morethan-2-duplicate-rows-and-sum-the-value-in-html-table-using-j)

Comment: You need to put more context, and maybe it would be perfect to post how you want the result html to look like.

Comment: Surely it should be done by script.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454888/1220550. It applies `rowspan`, but with some effort it could be made to work for `colspan` instead.

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question with a second table of how you expect the result to look afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Sub MergeSameCell()

```
Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xRows As Integer, xRows1 As Integer
Dim LastRowTE As Long

LastRowTE = Worksheets("Test_Execution").Cells(Worksheets("Test_Execution").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set WorkRng = Range("A2:A" & LastRowTE)
Set WorkRng1 = Range("B2:B" & LastRowTE)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
xRows1 = WorkRng1.Rows.Count

For Each Rng In WorkRng.Columns
    For i = 1 To xRows - 1
        For j = i + 1 To xRows
            If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge
        i = j - 1
    Next
Next

For Each Rng In WorkRng1.Columns
    For i = 1 To xRows1 - 1
        For j = i + 1 To xRows1
            If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        WorkRng1.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge
        i = j - 1
    Next
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Range("A1:O" & LastRowTE).WrapText = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Worksheets("Test_Execution").Rows("1:" & Worksheets("Test_Execution").Rows.Count).Delete
Call Worksheets("Requirement_JIRAs").SliceNDice
Call Worksheets("Test_Execution").vlookupJira
Call Worksheets("Test_Execution").DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria
Call Worksheets("Test_Execution").MergeSameCell
Call Worksheets("Test_Execution").FinalTableFormat
Call Worksheets("Test_JIRAs").StatusReport_TestingTable
```

End Sub